# How do I install Ubuntu on my laptop that has a new unformatted hard drive

Tags: boot

I've checked the system setup for priority of boot devices and still get a message saying a boot device can't be detected. I downloaded Ubuntu onto both a DVD and a USB stick (flash drive). The laptop is a Dell Latitude 5430.

Comment: How did you 'download' the image to a DVD or USB? Did you flash it or just copied it?

Comment: I believe I copied it to both DVD and flash drive. Sounds like I should have downloaded direct to flash drive?

Comment: Downloaded direct to the flash drive (.iso image) but still no joy.

Comment: 1. Use USB only. Now depending on the OS you're using to make the installation USB there are different tools you can use but in any case you won't be just saving the ISO to the media.

Comment: [This](https://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/dedhs1/how12275/how-to-create-a-live-ubuntu-linux-usb-key?lang=en) link from Dell, since you have a Dell Laptop, discribes how you create an Ubuntu Live USB stick from within Windows.